# Trouble building and installing glog with CMake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, glog

I'm using [Google glog](https://github.com/google/glog) as part of a larger project, and need to install and build it out of source using [CMake](https://cmake.org/) on Linux.

I am fairly new at using `CMake` and simply wish to build and use it for logging in the main project.

This is what I use to install the package but I can seem to figure out what commands to use since

```
ExternalProject_Add(glog_project
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/glog.git
    GIT_TAG v0.3.5
    SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/glog-src"
    BINARY_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/glog-build"
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND make
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    TEST_COMMAND ""
    LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
)
```

I am probably wrong in how I'm installing it, would appreciate any help.

**UPDATE:** After some great suggestions `glog`now but now it does not install properly. This is what I get when running `cmake`.[image]

Comment: `INSTALL_COMMAND ""` is for *disabling* install step. If you need installation, set actual installation command (like `INSTALL_COMMAND make install`). BTW, glog sources requires configuration step, either with CMake or with Autotools. But you have disabled this step too: `CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""`.

Comment: Thanks for the input, changing `INSTALL_COMMAND` and removing `CONFIGURE_COMMAND` got it to build but now I'm faced with getting it to install. [This](https://i.gyazo.com/8a85640566533b86b6022c0567cc8c96.png) is what I get from the terminal

Comment: The error on screenshot means, probably, that you are under non-root user, which cannot write files under `/usr/`.

Comment: That makes sense, now everything builds and compiles. Thank you so much!